# asp.net charts - show numbers

Tags: asp.net, charts, pie-chart

I use a Pie chart. I want it to display the percent or the values on the chart. How can I do this?

It is basic asp.net charting controls

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do this:

```
chart.Series["Default"].Label = "#PERCENT{P2}";
chart.Series["Default"].LegendText = "#VALX";
```

More info is available here:

[How to: Display Percentage Values on a Pie Chart](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc281298.aspx)